# Russian equivalents of "a grain of truth"

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I wanted to express the idea of "a grain of truth" and said:

> В том, что он говорит, безусловно, есть доля правды.

Now I'm wondering if the following could have worked as well? Or can it be misconstrued as some physical object being there?

> В том, что он говорит – там, безусловно, что-то есть.

Comment: **что-то есть** to me sounds less certain and conclusive than **есть доля правды**, and the pronoun **там** is unnecessary because it duplicates the adverbial of location **в том, что он говорит**, neither the dash is necessary and comma after **безусловно**, final result is  `В том, что он говорит, безусловно что-то есть`

Comment: There's a set expression _рациональное зерно_, most often used in scientific discussions (but not limited to formal usage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previos commentors said, "В этом что-то есть" is not quite what you want, and rather means "I like something about it" or even "it does make sense".
Your first sentence fits perfectly, also you can use proposed options or even the collocation "зерно истины" wich is also pretty common.

Comment: +1 for this one - it's exactly "зерно истины"

Answer (score 3):

**В этом что-то есть** is used in this meaning. But in your sentence it should be used without **там**. It is rather colloquial and may sound less certain, as noted above.

Also **в этом** (ваших словах, твоей идее) **есть зерно здравого смысла**, **доля истины**, **здравый смысл** (common sence).